# Optimize socket byte data

Tags: c#, sockets, optimization, byte

I'm writing a simple I/O class in order to use at a multiplayer game. Actually everything is Ok, but I'm trying find a way to optimize it in both overall performance and packet sizes.
The class is [here](http://pastebin.com/nUskiVyS)

Also, few days ago I found [this](http://pastebin.com/f23184cce) class and saw that it works directly on the bits. Doing that would be better to improve my class?

Thanks and sorry for the poor english.

Edit:
I'm using TCP, and the packet layout is the header (single byte) followed by entropy data (String, Int16, Int32, Int64, byte and byte array).
The packet max size is 4kb.

Comment: What are you really trying to optimize for? Latency? Total bandwidth? Client side processing? Server side processing?

Comment: The answer would likely depend on the details of your messaging protocol. To best be able to help you we would need to know specific field domains (data type, min/max length, valid values, etc) and message layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and the packet layout is the
>
> - header (single byte)
> - String
> - Int16
> - Int32
> - Int64
> - byte
> - byte array

That package cannot be optimized more if you cant reduce the size of any of the fields.

4kb data is roughly 32kbit/s which means that you can transmit a package to about 300 clients per second on a 10mbit/s connection. Are you saying that you need to handle more clients per second?

The best way to optimize your application is likely to use a buffer pool instead of creating a new buffer for each packet to send.

And as always: Don't optimize until you really need it, since you'll likely have to sacrifice readability.